# Error .xml "error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix"

Tags: android, xml, animation, fadein, alpha

Im trying to make a fadein animation but it gives me this error:

```
error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix
```

This is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set>
<alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0"
       android:toAlpha="1.0"
       android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
       android:duration="3000">
</alpha>
</set>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the unbound prefix in your case is `android`. add

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

to your set. E.g.

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

xmln is the [namespace](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/)

Answer (score 2):

First node (the `set`) needs to contain

`xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`